# Display titles of different cards in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-for

How can I display to v-dialog the data coming from my database?

```
<v-row class="albumLayout">
            <div v-for="(album, index) in allAlbums" :key="index">
              <v-col>
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-title>{{album.ALBUM}}</v-card-title>

                  <v-btn color="green" style="margin:10px" @click="dialog = !dialog">VIEW ALBUM</v-btn>

                  <v-btn color="red" style="margin:10px">DELETE ALBUM</v-btn>

                  <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
                    <v-card>
                      <v-card-title>{{album.ALBUM}}</v-card-title>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-dialog>
                </v-card>
              </v-col>
            </div>
</v-row>
```

As of now, it just display the I AM TITLE #3 every time I clicked **view album button** of each card.

[image]

Question is, how can I change this to show titles to each specific card.

Comment: remove the v-dialog from the loop, and instead of `@click="dialog = !dialog"` pass the clicked item/model to the dialog component something like `@click="dialog(album)"`, remember in Vue your passing around models, not manipulating the dom.

Comment: It doesn't work tho. After following your advice it didn't load the page.

Comment: what does the console say?

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler needs to do 2 things:  Set the album and show the dialog.

1. add selectedAlbum:null to your data
2. to open the dialog on click, set selectedAlbum = album
3. set the dialog model to !!selectedAlbum, to only show when album is set
4. use selectedAlbum instead of album in your dialog
5. To close set selectedAlbum to null